# OpenCV, IOS, template matching, place of good matching

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

i try to create an app like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9LY8JqKLqE&feature=my_liked_videos&list=LLIeJ9s3lwD-lrqYMU409iAQ

but sadly i dont know how to mark the place of finding

i was re-thinking this tutorial: http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/face-tracking/

my source code:
i implement the template image into the DemoVideoCaptureViewController.mm file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  

    UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tt2.jpg"];  
    tempMat = [testImage CVMat];  

    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;  
    cv::SurfFeatureDetector surf (250);  
    surf.detect(tempMat, keypoints);  

    cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor surfDesc;  
    surfDesc.compute(tempMat, keypoints, description1);  
}
```

and i try to find object here:

```
- (void)processFrame:(cv::Mat &)mat videoRect:(CGRect)rect videoOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)videOrientation
{

    cv::FlannBasedMatcher matcher;  
    std::vector< cv::vector<cv::DMatch> > matches;  
    std::vector<cv::DMatch>  good_matches;  

    cv::SurfFeatureDetector surf2 (250);  
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> kp_image;  

    surf2.detect(mat, kp_image);  
    cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor surfDesc2;  
    surfDesc2.compute(mat, kp_image, des_image);  

    if ((des_image.rows > 0) && (description1.rows  > 0)) {  

        matcher.knnMatch(description1, des_image, matches, 2);  

        for (int i = 0; i < MIN(des_image.rows-1, (int) matches.size()); i++) {

            if ((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size() <= 2 && (int) matches[i].size() > 0)) {
                good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
            }

        }

        [CATransaction begin];  
        [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];  

        **//remove old layer**  

        for (CALayer *layer in self.view.layer.sublayers) {  
            NSString *layerName = [layer name];  
            if ([layerName isEqualToString:@"Layer"])  
                [layer setHidden:YES];  
        }  

        [CATransaction commit];  

        if (good_matches.size() >= 4) {  
            NSLog(@"Finding");  
        }  
    }  
}
```

But i dont know how to put a layer on the camrea view

could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The app in the video you posted can be created following the chapter 3 (Marker-less Augmented Reality) from the book "Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects".

You still have to do some steps, like calculating the homography. And you don't need to use CATransaction or any other iOS class. CvVideoCamera and line is enough.